# Which Browserslist string covers "Chrome for iOS?"

Tags: ios, google-chrome, browser, build, browser-support

I see `Chrome`, `ChromeAndroid`, and `iOS` in the [current Browserslist list](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/blob/4.11.1/README.md#browsers), but I'm not sure which one covers "Chrome for iOS." https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#chrome_for_ios_user_agent makes me think it would be covered under `iOS`, but I'm not sure that is correct.

Which Browserslist string covers "Chrome for iOS?"